# Linking button to another viewcontroll (uiwebview)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

can anyone help? I have two different view controllers in my storyboard. First controller has buttons which I want to connect to a second controller which is a uiwebview, for it to open a website, I know how to make the buttons open the website in safari, but how do I tell the button to open it up in the second view controller insted of it just working with the first one? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Segues](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-Storyboarding-Tutorial-using-Segues-Scenes-ViewControllers-Navigation) to make a link to another UIViewConroller from the Storyboard.

Comment: Yes I have linked the button up to the other viewcontroller which has the webview in it, but when I click the button it still opens the website in safari and not inside the uiwebview? How do I tell it to open up in the webview?